# How does adding only dimensions to a table visual not show all combinations?

Tags: powerbi

I have 3 dimensions. Date, supplier, country; and 1 factSales

I create a table visual with country, supplier. I'm expecting this should show the same set of suppliers for each country. Like a cross join.

But interestingly it is only showing those suppliers against the country for which there is a fact entry. Why is that?

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the table visual is designed to do that.  If you open the Performance Analyzer, you'll see it generates a query like:

```
// DAX Query
DEFINE
    VAR __DS0Core = 
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            KEEPFILTERS(
                FILTER(
                    KEEPFILTERS(
                        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
                            'Country'[Country],
                            'Supplier'[Supplier],
                            "CountRowsSales", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Sales'))
                        )
                    ),
                    OR(
                        NOT(ISBLANK('Country'[Country])),
                        NOT(ISBLANK('Supplier'[Supplier]))
                    )
                )
            ),
            "'Country'[Country]", 'Country'[Country],
            "'Supplier'[Supplier]", 'Supplier'[Supplier]
        )

    VAR __DS0PrimaryWindowed = 
        TOPN(501, __DS0Core, 'Country'[Country], 1, 'Supplier'[Supplier], 1)

EVALUATE
    __DS0PrimaryWindowed
```

Generally PowerBI visuals don't show blank values.  You can configure the visual to [Show items with no data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-show-items-no-data).

Comment: So it queries the fact table even thought the fact table column isn't participating in the table visual?

Comment: How can I make it behave like a cross apply?

Comment: Interesting that the "Show items with no data" generates a load more DAX on top of this for its cartesian product rather than something much simpler.

Comment: Yep.  It wraps the SUMMARIZECOLUMNS with ADDMISSINGITEMS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/addmissingitems-function-dax

Comment: Can I make the default to show cross join output. I mean when I only add country and supplier to table visual.

Comment: No. There’s no setting to make “Show items with no data” the default.